# Separar caracteres de un char para encerrar cada uno en diferentes variables

Tags: c++, string

Verán, estoy usando Borland C++ ver 5.02 (se que es un compilador viejo pero aun así me gustaría saber si hay forma de ponerle fin a mi delirio) necesito que mi programa lea los caracteres del char y los separe en diferentes variables despues de una coma, pero por el momento solo necesito separar el char dentro de otras variables, esto es lo que llevo.

```
main()
{
    char *txt[100];
    cout<<"Ingresa texto: "
    gets(*txt);
    printf("%.*s", 4, txt + 10);
    getch();
    }
```

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia? Por lo que yo sé Borland no deja usar strings.

Comment: Tu variable `txt` no es una cadena de 100 caracteres, sino un array de 100 punteros a `char`. Quita el `*` de la declaración. Cuando llamas a `gets()` tienes que pasarle la dirección en que debe dejar el texto leido. Esto sería la dirección del array `txt`, que se obtiene poniendo el nombre del array sin decoradores. Es decir `gets(txt)`. En cuanto al resto de la pregunta, ni idea de qué pretendes hacer ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de entrada y salida esperadas?

Answer (score 2):

> Por lo que yo sé Borland no deja usar strings.

Mentira.

> ¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

1. Usa `std::string`, da igual lo antiguo que sea el compilador.
2. Main requiere tipo de retorno, si no tu programa no compila.
3. Usa `std::getline` con `std::stringstream`, puedes pedirle que corte las líneas con comas (`,`).
4. Usa `std::cout`, la función `std::printf` es de C, si ya estás usando `std::cout` antes no entiendo por qué cambias a `std::printf` después.

```
int main()
{
    std::string txt;
    std::cout << "Ingresa texto: ";
    std::cin >> txt;

    std::stringstream ss(txt);
    std::string valor;
    while (std::getline(ss, valor, ','))
        std::cout << valor << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te podías haber ahorrado `stringstream` y leer directamente desde `cin`... y te falta un `;` en el primer `cout` (en la pregunta tambien falta pero esta es la respueta :P)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, pero es lo mejor que puedo hacer con mis dotes de adivinación... las cuales me han dicho que el usuario que preguntó lo necesitaba en dos pasos.

Comment: Sí, sería de agradecer que hubiese puesto un ejemplo de entrada y la salida esperada